# DPDK linkage gives undefined symbol: rte_cpu_get_flag_enabled

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build a dynamic library ‘libdpdk.so’ of my own functions linked to the 3rd party DPDK libraries. I would then link ‘libdpdk.so’ to my own main.cpp test program. The problem I have is that ‘libdpdk.so’ builds without error but, when I link it to main.cpp I see undefined symbols. In fact, if I run ‘nm -u’ on ‘libdpdk.so’ I see quite a few undefined symbols.

Here is the linker command for the building ‘libdpdk.so’ (I have removed the absolute dpdk paths for clarity):

```
[14/15] : && /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++ -fPIC -march=native -g -O3 -DNDEBUG   -shared -Wl,-soname,libdpdk.so -o dpdk/libdpdk.so dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/ThreadDpdk.cpp.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/DpdkSock.cpp.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/Log.c.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/cfg.cpp.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/wrap_eth.cpp.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/wrap_ip.cpp.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/SocketClass.cpp.o dpdk/CMakeFiles/dpdk.dir/RingClass.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/dpdk/dpdk-stable-18.11.8/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib  /usr/lib64/libdl.so  /usr/lib64/libutil.so  /usr/lib64/libm.so  -Xlinker  -export-dynamic  -Wl,--whole-archive  librte_flow_classify.so  librte_pipeline.so  librte_table.so  librte_port.so  librte_pdump.so  librte_distributor.so  librte_ip_frag.so  librte_meter.so  librte_lpm.so  librte_acl.so  librte_jobstats.so  librte_metrics.so  librte_bitratestats.so  librte_latencystats.so  librte_power.so  librte_efd.so  librte_bpf.so  librte_cfgfile.so  librte_gro.so  librte_gso.so  librte_hash.so  librte_member.so  librte_vhost.so  librte_kvargs.so  librte_mbuf.so  librte_net.so  librte_ethdev.so  librte_bbdev.so  librte_cryptodev.so  librte_security.so  librte_compressdev.so  librte_eventdev.so  librte_rawdev.so  librte_timer.so  librte_mempool.so  librte_mempool_ring.so  librte_ring.so  librte_pci.so  librte_eal.so  librte_cmdline.so  librte_reorder.so  librte_sched.so  librte_kni.so  librte_common_cpt.so  librte_common_octeontx.so  librte_common_dpaax.so  librte_bus_pci.so  librte_bus_vdev.so  librte_bus_dpaa.so  librte_bus_fslmc.so  librte_mempool_bucket.so  librte_mempool_stack.so  librte_mempool_dpaa.so  librte_mempool_dpaa2.so  librte_pmd_af_packet.so  librte_pmd_ark.so  librte_pmd_avf.so  librte_pmd_avp.so  librte_pmd_axgbe.so  librte_pmd_bnxt.so  librte_pmd_bond.so  librte_pmd_cxgbe.so  librte_pmd_dpaa.so  librte_pmd_dpaa2.so  librte_pmd_e1000.so  librte_pmd_ena.so  librte_pmd_enic.so  librte_pmd_fm10k.so  librte_pmd_failsafe.so  librte_pmd_i40e.so  librte_pmd_ixgbe.so  librte_pmd_kni.so  librte_pmd_lio.so  librte_pmd_nfp.so  librte_pmd_null.so  librte_pmd_qede.so  librte_pmd_ring.so  librte_pmd_softnic.so  librte_pmd_sfc_efx.so  librte_pmd_tap.so  librte_pmd_thunderx_nicvf.so  librte_pmd_vdev_netvsc.so  librte_pmd_virtio.so  librte_pmd_vhost.so  librte_pmd_ifc.so  librte_pmd_vmxnet3_uio.so  librte_bus_vmbus.so  librte_pmd_netvsc.so  librte_pmd_bbdev_null.so  librte_pmd_null_crypto.so  librte_pmd_crypto_scheduler.so  librte_pmd_dpaa2_sec.so  librte_pmd_dpaa_sec.so  librte_pmd_virtio_crypto.so  librte_pmd_octeontx_zip.so  librte_pmd_qat.so  librte_pmd_skeleton_event.so  librte_pmd_sw_event.so  librte_pmd_dpaa_event.so  librte_pmd_dpaa2_event.so  librte_mempool_octeontx.so  librte_pmd_octeontx.so  librte_pmd_opdl_event.so  librte_pmd_skeleton_rawdev.so  librte_pmd_dpaa2_cmdif.so  librte_pmd_dpaa2_qdma.so  librte_bus_ifpga.so  librte_pmd_ifpga_rawdev.so  -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lrt  -lm  -lnuma  -ldl  /usr/lib64/libconfig.so  -Wl,-export  -Dynamic  -L/opt/dpdk/dpdk-stable-18.11.8/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib  -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-Map=dpdk_test.map  -Wl,--cref  -pthread && :
```

Here are the undefined symbols in libdpdk.so:

```
$ nm -u dpdk/libdpdk.so
                 U access@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U bzero@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U calloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U config_destroy
                 U config_init
                 U config_lookup
                 U config_read_file
                 U config_setting_get_elem
                 U config_setting_length
                 U config_setting_lookup_int
                 U config_setting_lookup_string
                 U __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U __cxa_begin_catch@@CXXABI_1.3
                 U __cxa_end_catch@@CXXABI_1.3
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U exit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fflush@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fprintf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fputs@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U free@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fwrite@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U gettimeofday@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U gp_threadDpdk
                 U g_shutdownNow
                 U g_shutdownNowMutex
                 U g_threadsMayRunCondVar
                 U g_threadsMayRunFlag
                 U g_threadsMayRunMutex
                 U __gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3
                 U inet_addr@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U lcore_config@@DPDK_2.0
                 U localtime@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14
                 U memset@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U per_lcore__lcore_id@@DPDK_2.0
                 U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w pthread_mutex_lock@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w pthread_mutex_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_self@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_spin_init@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_spin_lock@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_spin_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U putchar@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U rte_cpu_get_flag_enabled@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_cycles_vmware_tsc_map@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_delay_us@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_eal_get_configuration@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_eal_init@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_eth_dev_configure@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_dev_count_avail@@DPDK_18.05
                 U rte_eth_devices@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_dev_info_get@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_dev_is_valid_port@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_dev_start@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_link_get_nowait@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_macaddr_get@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_promiscuous_enable@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_rx_queue_setup@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_eth_tx_queue_setup@@DPDK_2.2
                 U rte_get_tsc_hz@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_hash_add_key@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_hash_create@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_hash_iterate@@DPDK_2.1
                 U rte_hash_lookup@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_ip_frag_free_death_row@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_ip_frag_table_create@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_ipv4_fragment_packet@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_ipv4_frag_reassemble_packet@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_ipv6_frag_reassemble_packet@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_lpm6_create@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_lpm_add@@DPDK_16.04
                 U rte_lpm_create@@DPDK_16.04
                 U rte_mempool_create@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_mempool_lookup@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_mempool_ops_table@@DPDK_16.07
                 U __rte_panic@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_pktmbuf_dump@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_pktmbuf_init@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_pktmbuf_pool_create@@DPDK_2.1
                 U rte_pktmbuf_pool_init@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_ring_create@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_socket_id@@DPDK_2.0
                 U rte_zmalloc_socket@@DPDK_2.0
                 U sched_getcpu@@GLIBC_2.6
                 U setbuf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U snprintf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U sprintf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U sscanf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U __strdup@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U strerror@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U strftime@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U __tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3
                 U _Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0
                 U vsnprintf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U __xpg_basename@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U _Z14get_sched_attrmRSs
                 U _Z5fatalRKSs
                 U _ZdlPv@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNKSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE3strEv@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_@@GLIBCXX_3.4.9
                 U _ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSs4_Rep9_S_createEmmRKSaIcE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSs4swapERSs@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSs6assignERKSs@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSsC1ERKSs@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ESt13_Ios_Openmode@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE@@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
                 U _ZNSt6localeC1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt6localeD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt8ios_baseD2Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l@@GLIBCXX_3.4.9
                 U _ZSt19__throw_logic_errorPKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZSt20__throw_system_errori@@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTISt9exception@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTTSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3
                 U _ZTVSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTVSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTVSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTVSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```

My test program fails to link with error:

```
[1/1] : && /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++  -march=native -g -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/Threads.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/ThreadMon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/ThreadMSG.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/_kbhit.cpp.o  -o dpdk_test  -Wl,-rpath,/data/daldrich/src/dpdk_test_library/build/dpdk  dpdk/libdpdk.so  -pthread && :
FAILED: dpdk_test 
: && /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++  -march=native -g -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/Threads.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/ThreadMon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/ThreadMSG.cpp.o CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/_kbhit.cpp.o  -o dpdk_test  -Wl,-rpath,/data/daldrich/src/dpdk_test_library/build/dpdk  dpdk/libdpdk.so  -pthread && :
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'rte_cpu_get_flag_enabled@@DPDK_2.0'
//opt/dpdk/dpdk-stable-18.11.8/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/lib/librte_eal.so.9.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Any ideas why symbol 'rte_cpu_get_flag_enabled@@DPDK_2.0' is undefined?

Comment: You have not linked with necessary libraries and compiler flags. Please recheck the link the same

Comment: @VipinVarghese I take your point. However, a clue may be that the missing symbol is 'rte_cpu_get_flag_enabled@@DPDK_2.0', whereas 'rte_cpu_get_flag_enabled' is defined in librte_eal.so. I wonder why '@@DPDK_2.0' is part of the mangled name of the missing symbol?

Comment: i have already covered these in https://github.com/vipinpv85/sessions/blob/master/session-2.txt and https://github.com/vipinpv85/sessions/blob/master/session3.txt. take a look.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I compared my link order and options with those of your session but the problem remains. Do you know where the @@DPDK_2.0 symbols come from?

Comment: Do I need librte-eal2 ? If so how do I build it?

Comment: I think this is fixed now. I am building with CMake and needed to declare the target libraries as PUBLIC not PRIVATE.

Comment: thanks for sharing that you are using CMake and not GNU make. Since this looks like an interesting issue please post the finding and solution as the answer as it will help the community.

Comment: waiting for your updates here

Comment: Hi @DavidA, I had a cross check on the the g++ CFLAGS and LDFLAGS arguments. Some of the items are not clear, 1. when building in the shared library is not lilbdpdk.so` is shared  and definitions for some functions are present in other shared libraries?, 2. Since your binary `dpdk_test` is build from shared library, `I do not see any setenv for LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Can you please cross check and update us